# scale random 3d model to fit in a viewport

Tags: opengl

How can I scale a random 3d model to fit in an opengl viewport? I am able to center the model in the middle of the view port. How do I scale it to fit it in the viewport. The model could be an airplane, a cone, an 3d object or any other random model.

Appreciate any help.

Comment: Do you want to actually scale the model or just move the camera so that the model "just fits" in the viewpoint?

Comment: Either will do as long as I see it the way it is displayed now. Think of looking at an airplane so you see the body and both wings. I want it to fit the entire viewport.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You'll need the following information:

- `r`: the radius of the object's [bounding sphere](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bounding_sphere)
- `z`: the distance from the object to the camera
- `fovy`: the vertical field of view (let's say in degrees) of the camera, as you might have passed it to `gluPerspective`

Make a little sketch of the situation, find the right triangle in there, and deduce the maximum radius of a sphere that would fit exactly. Given the above parameters, you should find `r_max = z * sin(fovy*M_PI/180 / 2)`.

From that, the scale factor is `r_max / r`.

All this assumes that the viewport is wider than it is high; if it's not, you should derive `fovx` first, and use that instead of `fovy`.

Comment: Of course if fovy is in radians, then simply use `r_max = z * sin(fovy/2)`.